# backbonejs: Cannot call method 'bind' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am currently learning backbone.js via a screencast tutorial, somewhere along the way, my code seems to stop working, throwing the error `Cannot call method 'bind' of undefined` in Chrome's javascript console. The erroneous line is contained in the `initialize` function:

```
window.PlaylistView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tag: 'section',
    className: 'playlist',

    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        this.template = _.template($('#playlist-template').html());
        this.collection.bind('reset', this.render);  //<<<<<< THIS LINE

        this.player = this.options.player;
        this.library = this.options.library;
    },

    render: function() {
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.player.toJSON()));

        this.$('button.play').toggle(this.player.isStopped());
        this.$('button.pause').toggle(this.player.isPlaying());

        return this;
    }
});
```

I don't know what `this.collection` means, why does the view have a collection, isn't collections for models? `this.collection.bind()` used in other views did not seem to throw any errors. In `window.LibraryAlbumView` which calls `this.collection.trigger('select', this.model);` and extends `window.AlbumView`, I dont see any collection defined anywhere in `window.AlbumView`, yet no error is thrown. This seems to be confusing me.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/UXM9s/)

**EDIT:**

The error has been fixed because instead of

```
window.Player = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            'currentAlbumIndex': 0,
            'currentTrackIndex': 0,
            'state': 'stop'
        },

        initialize: function() {
            this.playlist = new Playlist();
        },
```

I had

```
window.Player = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            'currentAlbumIndex': 0,
            'currentTrackIndex': 0,
            'state': 'stop'
        },

        initialize: function() {
            playlist = new Playlist();    // <<< this line changed!
        },
```

Also previously `this.collection` refered to the collection here,

```
window.BackboneTunes = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '': 'home',
        'blank': 'blank'
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this.playlistView = new PlaylistView({
            collection: window.player.playlist,  // <<<< THIS ONE!
            player: window.player,
            library: window.library
        });

        this.libraryView = new LibraryView({
            collection: window.library
        });
    },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backbone Views contain a collection or a model, because views are meant for presenting the data contained within a model or a collections of models.

This example throws an error because this.collection has not been defined yet. To do that you need to initialize some collection and then pass it on to your view.

`new PlayListView({collection: someCollection});`

Comment: Thanks, I followed your response and solved the error as updated in original post. I missed out the `this.` in `this.playlist = new Playlist();` What is the difference between `this.playlist` and `playlist`? Is `playlist` global and if its global, why would this cause the error since every object will be able to access `playlist`

Comment: in javascript `this` is usually never what you expect it to be. That's why you should use underscore.js' `_.bindAll(this, 'methodname', 'methodname2', ...)` method in all view and collection initialize methods to bind this to the collection's or view's methods. With `this.playlist` you declared the playlist to be a part of `window.player`, so it could be accessed with `window.player.playlist`